# How can I configure Telegram to open links using Opera Browser instead of Chrome?

Tags: default-applications, telegram

My Android is v6, but answers for any other modern version are OK too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Better open with](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith), reset all defaults and use that to select the Telegram link to show an option to open with other browsers ( I don't have Opera installed but you can see other browsers in the screenshot below). You can set it by "always open with" or give you the choice to select (it has a timer option for selection)

[image: IMG:]

click to enlarge