# Firefox for Android: How to change upload app?

Tags: firefox-for-android, uploads

I'm using 94.1.2 on Android 11.
For upload handling I accidentally set a file manager app.
Now I want to change the app or at least get the request popup back, which asks me which app (Google Photos, Camera, File Manager, ...) I want to use.

Comment: Solution here should work https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228920/131553

Comment: @beeshyams I resetted it, but this only brought back the "open with" prompt for web links, the upload  action is still associated to the the file manager.

Comment: Maybe uninstall that file manager? If it works you can install that file manager again and not associate with upload?

Comment: Unfortunately the file manager can't be uninstalled (MIUI system). Erasing its settings didn't affect the upload prompt in Firefox.

Comment: Try disabling the file manager and choose using better open with app

Comment: I can't disable it. I can end it but will automatically start again once I tap a file upload button.

Comment: Last try - uninstall Firefox and then install and see if behavior changes