# how do I prevent the 'open with' dialog from popping up?

Tags: applications, browser

I'd like to know if it's possible to disable this dialog:
[image]

Two apps I'm trying to use at the moment open this darn dialog window: Tailscale and GitHub. I'd like to open the links *inside* the respective applications. GitHub works, but I was going to submit an issue and the GitHub app is trying to force me to open it in the browser. As far as Tailscale goes, I can't log in because it redirects me to the external browser instead of opening inside the app, thus not receiving the hash that's required for logging in.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228986/131553

Comment: @beeshyams Thank you. Unfortunately, that didn't work: for the GitHub issue, choosing GitHub as the application, just throws me back to the same page; for Tailscale, it just loops the 'Open with' dialog.